# Power series convergent but not uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

Suppose its radius of convergence $R=\infty$, I wonder if there is an example satisfying the condition in my title.

I already know when $R<\infty$ there is an example such as $\sum x^n$ in $(-1,1)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $e^x$. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: _Every_ power series with infinite radius of convergence that is not a polynomial has that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No power series with infinitely many nonzero coefficients converges uniformly on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, let $f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k a_nx^n$ and suppose $f_k$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.  Choose any $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N$ such that $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $x$ and any $k\geq N$.  Suppose $k> N$ is such that $a_k\neq 0$.  Then we can choose $x$ large enough so that $|a_kx^k|>2\epsilon$.  For such an $x$, $|f_{k}(x)-f_{k-1}(x)|>2\epsilon$, which is a contradiction since $f_{k}(x)$ and $f_{k-1}(x)$ are both within $\epsilon$ of $f(x)$.

This contradiction means that $a_k=0$ for all $k>N$.  In particular, only finitely many of the coefficients $a_k$ are nonzero.